# Having hard time solving inequality problems, what should I do?

Tags: inequality, book-recommendation, advice

I can't see the operations and symmetries required to solve a lot of those problems, which is extremely frustrating for me. I am trying to learn from "Inequalities- a math olympiad aproach" , and while there are detailed and clear solutions to problems the techniques and strategies presented are sometimes used only in one hard problem, which does not allow me to get familiar with the technique and practice it enough and build my control in it gradually.

So I'm asking myself now what should I do to progress more efficiently? What would help me see the operations that are needed to be done? 
Should I continue with this hard book and do my best tackling those problems, or move to an easier book? Maybe a book on problem solving such as Engel's? Maybe I lack knowledge in some other field such as polynomials (I never practiced that subject from an olympiad level book).

Would be glad for any help!

Comment: Practice a lot and mastership will follow.

Comment: I read a similar question, and there they advocated the book     [Cauchy Master Class][1]


  [1]: http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~ehudf/courses/Ineq09/The%20Cauchy-Schwarz%20Master%20Class%20.pdf